# How do I separate a dictionary's values so that they can be printed in different columns?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary in which the keys have two values. I need to print the dictionary in a table format, with each value in a different column. However, when I do it, the values are together in the same column.

This is the code:

```
mydic = {'1': [22, 23], '2': [33,24], '3': [44,25]}

print ("{:<10} {:<10} {:<10}".format('Number', 'Total', 'Percentage'))
    
for k, v in mydic.items():
    print(f"{k:11}{v}")
```

This prints this:

```
Number      Total       Percentage
1          [22, 23]
2          [33, 24]
3          [44, 25]
```

I want this:

```
Number      Total       Percentage
1          22            23
2          33            24
3          44            25
```

How do I separate the values so that they can go into their respective columns instead?

Comment: `for k, (total, percentage) in mydic.items():`

Comment: Your dict values are just a list. So `v[0]` and `v[1]` will work here. `print(f"{k:11}{v[0]}{v[1]}")`

Comment: @Rashid'Lee'Ibrahim Oh, thank you, you're right!

Comment: @satoru, it's called [unpacking](https://stackabuse.com/unpacking-in-python-beyond-parallel-assignment/).

Comment: In addition, I find `print(f"{k:<10} {total:<10} {percentage:<10}")` way clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this ?

```
print ("{:<10} {:<10} {:<10}".format('Number', 'Total', 'Percentage'))
for k, v in mydic.items():
    print(f"{k:11}{v[0]}{v[1]:11}")
```